# GetWindowRect returns wrong values on one application, all other applications are correct

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winapi

I am using GetWindowRect from the windows API to get the bounds of a running application, I then use these bounds to screenshot the application.

My code works for about 10 programs I have tested, notepad.exe and a few others, however the one app I want to use it with RocLink800 it returns static values that are incorrect regardless of the applications location.

Code is C# .NET

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct RECT
    {
        public int X;
        public int Y;
        public int Width;
        public int Height;
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, ref RECT Rect);

    IntPtr error = GetWindowRect(proc.MainWindowHandle, ref rect);

    ... main code
    while (error == (IntPtr)0)
    {
        error = GetWindowRect(proc.MainWindowHandle, ref rect);
    }

    int width = rect.right - rect.left;
    int height = rect.bottom - rect.top;
```

Now all applications this returns the correct width and height, with roclink800 it returns an error value of 1 indicating successs but it returns the following values regardless of the applications location:

rect.right = 960
rect.left = 960
rect.bottom = 600
rect.top = 600

I am completely stumped why this is happening or how to rectify it, roclink800 is an old program ported from the windows95 days so perhaps it is using some odd api, if this is the case are there any alternatives from the windows API (user32.dll) to obtaining its screen coordinates?

I guess I could force the application to go fullscreen and screen capture it this way but it is less elegant.

Ideas anyone?

edit: My code for getting the handle

```
        Process roclink = new Process();
        roclink.StartInfo.FileName = "C:/Program Files (x86)/ROCLINK800/Roclink.exe";
        //roclink.StartInfo.FileName = "notepad.exe";
        roclink.Start();
        IntPtr error = GetWindowRect(roclink.MainWindowHandle, ref rect);
```

OR

```
        try
        {
            proc = Process.GetProcessesByName("roclink")[0];
        }
        catch (IndexOutOfRangeException e)
        {
            return null;
        }
```

Both chunks of code return the same IntPtr and they both return 960,960,600,600 however if I call

```
int error = SetWindowPos(roclink.MainWindowHandle, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 25,50, SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
```

Then I get the returned coordinates being 0,0,25,50 yet the applications size does not change.

I have tried breaking the program, closing roclink and the SetWindowPos and GetWindowRect both return 0 and do not return the false values indicating that the handle is indeed the correct handle.

So it seems this application cannot have its windowsize set or gotten via windowsAPI, anyone got any clues why this may be?

```
roclink.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
```

This also is ignored and the application will not open in fullscreen, simply the size it was last opened in.

edit: The only solution I can come up with is to make a copy of roclink.exe and open it manually by hand fullscreen then close it, providing no one else opens this file it will always open full screen, this is dodgy and I do not like it but unless anyone has any ideas why this is the case I may have to go with this. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it is obvious that in the case of your application the `MainWindowHandle` is not the actual 'main window' the application launches.

Comment: Wow it really was this simple, for some reason I was getting a non zero value when getting the handle via "roclink" making me think it was successfully getting the handle, if I put gibberish in it returns a null value, but not with "roclink", how strange, I launched the app via a process and use process.MainWindowHandle and now it operates successfully. Thanks!

Comment: ok now it randomly works and randomly doesn't it alternates between giving the right coordinates, and then giving 960,960,600,600 again. Anyone know why my handle would give the right coordinates 1/10 times and then these garbage ones the rest of the time?

Comment: Even more bizarre, if I send SetWindowPos(roclink.MainWindowHandle, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 25,50, SWP_SHOWWINDOW); then it returns the coorindates of 0,0,25,50 but the application doesn't actually change its coordinates. Perhaps this gives credit to the point that it is the wrong handle, maybe a better question would be why is it returning the wrong handle? I'll update my question with the handle getting code.

Comment: What I suggesting is that the .MainWindowHandle property is not the actual window you are trying to get. Use SPY++ to compare the handle you are checking vs. the actual handle of the window.

Comment: You are correct it is the handle of something property within the form, how would I go about obtaining programatically this correct handle?

Comment: Used WinAPI FindWindow to find the window with the handle according to  spy++ and it now works perfectly, thanks for all your help, I've learnt something new out of this as well!

Answer (score 5):

Looking at the screenshot of this RockLink800 application it seems that this is a Delphi application, and old versions of Delphi had a hidden window that was Application.Handle.

Here is a SO answer how to get main window handle for old Delphi applications :

[Retrieving Delphi Window Handles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408898/retrieving-delphi-window-handles)

Comment: Thanks, this explains why I was having trouble finding the window handle, I used Rotems advice to locate the correct handle.